# Javascript - Ajax readyState stuck to 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have read all the threads I could find and tried to debug my code for hours, but I'm blocked and can't see why it does not work. It's certainly a stupid mistake.

Context : I want to sanitize data sent by a tinyMce plugin, before it arrives in the editor. And for that, I want to use a php function which already exists, for consistency AND to avoid rewriting 200 lines from php to js.

So I have my js for the editor, that works perfectly, except for the call to the sanitization script :

```
if ( lln_mytext_val != "" ) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 ) {

            lln_mytext_val = xhr.responseText ;
        }
        else {
            alert ( xhr.readyState+" - "+xhr.status ) ;
        }
    }

    xhr.open ( 'GET' , 'sanitize.php?the_slug='+lln_mytext_val , true ) ;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send (  ) ;

}
```

And in sanitize.php , there is a very simple code :

```
$tockeck_slug = $_GET['the_slug'] ; 

$newslug= sanitize_title( $tockeck_slug ) ;
$newslug = str_replace ( "-" , "_" , $newslug) ; 
if ( substr ( $newslug, 0 , 6 ) != 'llnfl_' ) 
    { $newslug= "llnfl_".$newslug; }
echo $newslug;
```

When I directly call sanitize.php in the browser, it works. 
I checked in Firefox console and I have no 404 and no js error

But when I use the js, I just get the alert with 1 - 0

(And of course, lln_mytext_val is not empty ! )

Comment: Can you show how these lines are called?

Comment: There are used in a TinyMCE plugin for WordPress. The structure is classical, with a window.php as a pop-up that loads a js file, and the function in the js file is referenced through WordPress TinyMCE functions. I also put the full url to the sanitize.php, does not make any difference. (the sanitize.php is at the same level as the .js file). 
Does that answer your question ? 

It is used to insert shortcodes in the editor, and the code around is working properly, the shortcode is included.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

When you are within TinyMce, the direct call to XMLHttpRequest is not functionning properly.

Using the [tinymce.util.XHR Class](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.util.XHR) solved the problem of being stucked in readyState 1